# How to position a widget outside ModalBottomSheet in flutter

Tags: flutter

How to position a widget outside ModalBottomSheet in flutter?

I have an icon and I want to put it outside the ModalBottomSheet as shown in the picture below

[image]

please provide me code to achieve such a widget

Comment: Try to using Stack with children are Circle Icon and Container with top left and top right radius

Comment: the problem is  when use show ModalBottomSheet method all widgets being inside its container  it. so I cant go out of its container

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you can do is create the bottom sheet as a column of two containers, and the first (bottom) container with transparent background. This way you can overcome the problem because the transparent container will be a part of the bottom sheet, and since you can put the icon (circle avatar etc.) "above" this container with `Stack`, the icon will be visible.

So combine `Stack` and `Positioned` to achieve the result:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const BottomSheetApp());

class BottomSheetApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomSheetApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Bottom Sheet Sample')),
          body: const BottomSheetExample(),
        ),
      );
}

class BottomSheetExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomSheetExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Show ModalBottomSheet'),
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet<void>(
              context: context,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return SizedBox(
                    height: 264,
                    child: Stack(children: [
                      Column(children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 64,
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                        ),
                        Container(
                            height: 200,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  const Center(child: Text('Well done')),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                  ElevatedButton(
                                    child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                  ),
                                ]))
                      ]),
                      Positioned(
                          left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 32,
                          top: 32,
                          child: const CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 32,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                            child: Icon(Icons.check, size: 24),
                          )),
                    ]));
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,This  is really working

Answer (score -1):

```
showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return CustomBottomSheet();
          },
        );

class CustomBottomSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
     color: Colors.white,
    child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 200,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: -50,
            child: ClipOval(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_right_rounded,
                size: 50
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      //add more widgets you need.
    ],
  ),
);
  }
}
```

Here call the bottomsheet and I have given an icon. Use whatever Icon or image you wish to add. Just added a stack in the bottomsheet.